# Image not loading after "build" in angular8

Tags: angular

The issue is the path of the image located in `"assets"` folder is not loading after `ng build`.

I am running `ng build` after changing the path to `<base href="/skstose/">` of `index.html`.

Dev environment means `ng serve`.
Prod environment means `ng build` after compiling.

1) The below issue is in dev environment:-

```
Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError:
Can't resolve 'assets/images/skistose/kgExtract.png' in 'E:\Workspace\skistose\src\app\skistose-kg-extract'

> 2 |   background: url("assets/images/skillStore/kgExtract.png") no-repeat;
                    ^
```

2) The below issue is in prod environment:-

## .css

```
.bg{
    background: url(/assets/images/skillStore/kgExtract.png) no-repeat
}
```

is working in `dev environement` but not in `prod environment`.

## .css

```
.bg{
    background: url(assets/images/skillStore/kgExtract.png) no-repeat
   }
```

is working in `prod environment` but not in `dev environment`.

However, `<img src="assets/images/skillStore/uploadFile.png">` is working fine in `dev environment` as well as `'prod environment'`.

In dev environment ,

```
 <base href="/">
```

In prod build:-

```
 <base href="/skstose/">
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont edit in index html;

for building in url try this code:-

> ng build --prod --base-href='/skstose/'

Url link will be open like this `'http:/test.com/skstose'`

Here is the resources:- https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: still same issue

Comment: url path will be same "url(assets/images/skillStore/kgExtract.png) no-repeat"

just build  with ng build --prod --base-href='/skstose/'

Comment: but in dev environment ng serve, its not loading image.

Comment: in dev server what did u put ur url path ?

Comment: background: url(/assets/images/skillStore/kgExtract.png) no-repeat ... this is working but background: url(assets/images/skillStore/kgExtract.png) no-repeat not working.

Comment: use this class .backgroundCLass{
    height:40em;
    background-size:cover;
    width:auto;
    background-image:url('assets/images/skillStore/kgExtract.png');
    background-position:50% 50%;
}
its working in dev.

Comment: did u try making class in div  ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting `assets` folder after `ng build` in your dist folder?

if not try with `ng build --prod` and check

Comment: I am just trying for ng build and changing the path  to <base href="/skstose/"> of index.html. When inspecting image on google chrome dev tool , the issue I found.

Answer (score 0):

Your file "index.html" must contain:

```
<base href="/">
```

Try searching for your image this way

```
background-image: url(../../../../../assets/My-image_2020.jpg);
```

And build your project whit

```
ng build --prod --base-href /skstose/
```

The end result(compiled) is in charge of giving context to your files

PD: to work locally it is not necessary to change the path in `<base href="/">` of `index.html`